# How can I find the items inside an object after using a Get request?

Tags: c#, json, linq

After I do my GET request to a server, I get the following object

```
{"hats": [{"material": "Glass", "model": "Cloud", "item": 2, "size": 22, "id": 35}, {"material": "Glass", "model": "Cloud", "item": 2, "size": 35, "id": 99}, {"material": "Glass", "model": "Mib Factory", "item": 2, "size": 48, "id": 186}, {"material": "Glass", "model": "Llamacorn", "item": 2, "size": 12, "id": 208}], "nextPage": false, "numPages": 1, "currentPage": 1}
```

I can stringify the entire object and see it as is. But, I would like the individual items in the object. Based on this json, there is 1 main one "hats" which contains an array of more objects that include "material", "model", "item", "size", "id". How can I retrieve these properties?

I would like to eventually make a query in LINQ based on this object. For example, find if there is a material of type "Glass" in the object.

Comment: You go to http://QuickType.io and paste your data in, the. generate a set of stub data classes and parser there. Afterwards, follow the instructions given in the sample code, for how to use it :)

Comment: @CaiusJard That worked. I didn't realize I needed a class and its variables already made. I'm too used to using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you get that in an ajax response on your front end, then take the JSON string, parse it using JSON.parse(result), and then access it like any other object in JavaScript.

If you get that result in your server, you will need to use Json.NET to deserailize it into a custom class defined to hold those values.